# TypeScript data mapper function argument infers never

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Consider the following example:

```js
type columns = {
    A: number;
    B: string;
    C: boolean;
};
const mapper: { [T in keyof columns]: (item: columns[T]) => string } = {
    A: item => `${item}`,
    B: item => item,
    C: item => (item ? "Good" : "Bad"),
};
const data: columns[] = [
    { A: 0, B: "Hello", C: true },
    { A: 1, B: "World", C: false },
];
const keys: (keyof columns)[] = ["A", "B", "C"];
data.map(item => keys.map(key => mapper[key](item[key] as never)));
// should return [["0", "Hello", "Good"], ["1", "World", "Bad"]]
```

In the last line, `key` is of type `keyof columns`, i.e. `"A" | "B" | "C"`, which makes `mapper[key]` reduce to `(item: number & string & boolean) => string`, i.e. `(item: never) => string`. (Point out if my concept is wrong.)

So the question is, how can I rewrite the code such that `item[key]` does not need to be casted to `never`?

Comment: Type names are conventially written in UpperPascalCase so I've switched `columns` to `Columns` in my answer.  Also, type parameters for key types are more conventionally given names like `K` (for key) or `P` (for property) so I've switched `T in keyof columns` to `K in keyof Columns` in my answer code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general limitation with TypeScript and the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The compiler is really not able to look at a single expression like `mapper[key](item[key])` and use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to analyze it to see that it's safe.

The problem is that `mapper[key]` and `item[key]` are both of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  The type of `mapper[key]` is `((item: number) => string) | ((item: string) => string) | ((item: boolean)=>string)` and the type of `item[key]` is `number | string | boolean`.  But the compiler has no good way to keep track of the *correlation* between the types of those values.  It treats all unions as essentially independent of each other.  We know that `mapper[key]` is `(item: number) => string` exactly when `item[key]` is `number`, but the compiler doesn't.  For all it understands, `mapper[key]` could accept a `number` while `item[key]` is `string`.  The correlation has to do with the fact that we're using the same `key` in both expressions, but the compiler only tracks the type of `key`, and not its identity.

When you treat `mapper[key]` and `item[key]` independently, you're kind of stuck.  You can only call a union of function types [with arguments that would work for every member of the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  That is, an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the parameters... so the compiler sees `mapper[key]` as assignable to `(item: number & string & boolean) => string`, aka `(item: never) => string`... meaning such a function is never safe to call in general.

Until and unless there is some way to tell the compiler to track correlations between expressions of union type, there's no great way to proceed.  If you care about type safety above all else, you can write some redundant code to get it:

```
data.map(item => keys.map(key =>
  key === "A" ? mapper[key](item[key]) :
    key === "B" ? mapper[key](item[key]) :
      mapper[key](item[key])
)); // no error but it's redundant and repetitive 
// and also redundant
```

If you care about convenience instead of type safety, then you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress errors.  Your example of `item[key] as never` is one way to do it, although you're technically lying about what `item[key]` is.  If you don't want to lie you can use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) callback function like this:

```
data.map(item => keys.map(<K extends keyof Columns>(key: K) =>
  (mapper[key] as (item: Columns[K]) => string)(item[key]) // okay
));
```

You have to assert that `mapper[key]` is a value of type `(item: Columns[K]) => string)` because the compiler can't verify that, even though it theoretically should be able to.  It eagerly resolves `mapper[key]` to a union of functions when you try to call it.  And since `mapper[key]` truly is a value of that type, we're not lying.  The lack of type safety here comes from the fact that if someone evil switched around `mapper`'s entries, the compiler wouldn't notice:

```
const evilMapper = {
  A: mapper.B,
  B: mapper.C,
  C: mapper.A
}

data.map(item => keys.map(<K extends keyof Columns>(key: K) =>
  (evilMapper[key] as (item: Columns[K]) => string)(item[key]) // okay?!
));
```

whereas the redundantly redundant version would start screaming about it:

```
data.map(item => keys.map(key =>
  key === "A" ? evilMapper[key](item[key]) : // error
    key === "B" ? evilMapper[key](item[key]) : // error
      evilMapper[key](item[key]) // error
));
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2BnKBeKBvAWACgooBBALijVQCMIAnAbmNICEqNgGBLNAcxYlYVWnEQQAhmiEBfIQGM4mYFBSSwkBlTxQA2gGkofKAGsIIOADNYiVJgC6VABQ9gEFFXjJ0GQw4BKHAA+KC5eAShZHHxWcio3DxCoAAMAEjxElFkUgBo4jmN3FGSs-OEYBOLk12qAfigAIgBxcQATRqgqRrZJDoDy+WIlFSg2yWBJLztfPQcYvTjdSigABlyoQsaACQgEBDhGjcqobiRoWXLSZaoARg2tgHU4BgQO46orSQQMC-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)

Comment: Great and thanks for the detailed answer! I know that there must be many similar questions and issues in StackOverflow and in the official repo but I didn't know what keywords should I use to search for them. From your link, I've noticed there's a PR opened yesterday aiming to solve this problem. It's a pleasure to know that it's TypeScript's limitation but not my fault. Thank you again very much!